# querying free restaurant tables with hours on a specific date and according to work shifts in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The table structures are as follows:

```
Tables:
Id  Number  Title
1   1       VIP-1
2   2       VIP-2

WorkShifts:
Id  DayOfWeek  From   To
1   Sunday     08:00  12:00
2   Sunday     17:00  20:00
3   Monday     18:00  23:00

Applications:
Id   CustomerId   TableId   Date        From   To
1    1            1         2020-02-23  08:00  09:30
2    3            2         2020-02-23  10:00  11:00
```

keep in mind that the minimum reserve time is 1 hour. 
based on the information above how to query free tables(with time) in  specific date? 
for example on Sunday February 23, 2020 ('2020-02-23') the result should be:

```
TableId   Time
1         10:00
1         11:00
1         17:00
1         18:00
1         19:00
2         08:00
2         09:00
2         11:00
2         17:00
2         18:00
2         19:00
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Can an application extend past midnight, e.g. `2020-02-29` from `22:00` to `04:30`? A _numbers_ (aka _tally_) table is likely to be useful with an `outer join`.

Comment: No, an application only can be extended by work shift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different ways finally problem solved with this stored procedure:

```
create procedure GetFreeHourByTable @Date date as 

declare @startTime time(0), @endTime time(0), @day int

declare @dates table (day int, time time(0))

DECLARE cursor_shifts CURSOR
FOR SELECT 
        w.DayOfWeek, w.StartTime, w.EndTime 
    FROM 
        WorkingTimes w where w.DayOfWeek = DATEPART(dw, @Date) and w.IsDayOff = 0;

OPEN cursor_shifts;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_shifts INTO 
    @day,
    @startTime, 
    @endTime;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        while @startTime < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, @endTime)
        begin
            set @startTime = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @startTime)

            insert into @dates values (@day, @startTime)
        end

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_shifts INTO 
        @day,
        @startTime, 
        @endTime;
    END;

CLOSE cursor_shifts;
DEALLOCATE cursor_shifts;

select t.*, d.* from @dates d, Tables t
where d.day =  DATEPART(dw, @Date) 
and not exists 
(select * from Applications a 
    where a.tableId = t.id and a.registerDate = @Date and d.time between a.startTime and a.endTime)
```

so we can query free tables(by date) with hours :

```
exec GetFreeHourByTable @Date = '2020-02-23';
```